# Something weird is happening with Fn keys

Tags: nvidia, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, brightness

I have an Asus N56JR with NVIDIA GeForce 760M.
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
There are a few things wrong with my Fn keys. For one the brightness (controlled with Fn+F5 and Fn+F6) do not respond at all. Even commands in the terminal and programs that i have installed do not affect the screen brightness.
The second problem that I have is that the keyboard back-light (controlled with Fn+F3 and Fn+F4) do not seem to follow a regular outcome. The keyboard brightness up key sometimes decreases the light and other times increases it. This is seemingly random. The same happens with eh keyboard brightness down button. Along with those two buttons, there is a button in the top left of the keyboard that matches that power button. This is a button used to configure anything to. Just a blank button usually. I created a custom shortcut to launch an application from it (it works fine) but sometimes it gets mixed up with the keyboard brightness keys. These 3 keys seem to switch with each other at random intervals.

Comment: I have a similar problem with the lower volume / raise volume Fn keys in my keyboard. If other keys are assigned the commands work fine, but Fn keys simply won't work.

Answer (score 0):

[For your FN-Brightness Key]

Open your Terminal and run this:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and search for

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
```

and change it into

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
```

It should work for Asus as for Acer PCs too. It worked for my Acer.

Answer (score 0):

On my Asus k55v, brightness & rfkill (wifi on/off) where not working when I install Debian. As *buntu derives from Debian, you can try adding "acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'" to your kernel command line modifying the file /etc/default/grub at line GRUB_CMD_LINE_DEFAULT=.
It should see like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
```

Then execute, as root, update-grub. Reboot and it should be done. Maybe, then, you need to reassign these keys (fn+f5 and f6) to system's brightness actions on your keyboard settings, at hotkeys section.
That worked for me, and I have all fn keys working on my system (asus k55v laptop, as I've said). even fn+f4 (not marked, launches www browser).